# How to call a filename with parameters stored inside a powershell object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This script works

```
$runFile = '.\runFile.ps1'
& $runFile
```

This script doesn't

```
$runFile = '.\runFile.ps1 -var "1"'
& $runFile
```

The second one doesn't seem to work because I'm trying to called runFile.ps1 with a variable.

Is this possible to do in powershell?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - actually no, i did run & $runFile. Sorry, this isn't my real code, I just wrote an example.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I get this error when i do & : The term '.\runFile.ps1 -var "1"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - ok so I can do this "& $runFile $p", however, I have multiple parameters in $p and it just treats it as the first parameter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.` or `&` to make the call, use `Invoke-Expression`.

Assuming a runFile.ps1 with the following content

```
## runFile.ps1
param (
    $var = "default1",
    $p = "default2"
)

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object $var
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue -Object $p
```

Do this:

```
$run = ".\runFile.ps1 -var 'awesome' -p 'cool stuff'"
Invoke-Expression -Command $run
```

Quoting gets tricky. Be careful.